# What is the best way to architecture a React template using props children?

Tags: reactjs, containers, react-props

I'm using React to build out a single template that is being used by multiple pages. I'm using the idea of containment with `props.children` to achieve that.

Everything is working fine, but I'm finding it increasingly annoying to instantiate the page component *each* time, because the template has a lot of required props.

```
<PageTemplate
  something={true}
  somethingElse={myVar}
  anotherThing={something}>
  <Home />
</PageTemplate>

<PageTemplate
  something={true}
  somethingElse={myVar}
  anotherThing={something}>
  <About />
</PageTemplate>

<PageTemplate
  something={true}
  somethingElse={myVar}
  anotherThing={something}>
  <Products />
</PageTemplate>
```

As you can see, `<Home />`, `<About />` and `<Products />` all live within the `<PageTemplate />` component. Again, this works well, but repeating the same props per instance seems redundant. Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: sounds like a use case for a higher-order component. check this out: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're not making each "page" its own react app then this sounds like something React Router is set up to solve.

If you were to use this you could have one `<PageTemplate>` component with a `<Router>` that renders the different pages.

It's markup would probably look like

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
    <PageTemplate
        something={true}
        somethingElse={myVar}
        anotherThing={something}
    >
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/about">
                <About />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/products">
                <Products />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
                <Home />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </PageTemplate>
</Router>
```

If this `<PageTemplate>` component is being used in multiple react apps it would probably be made a bit better using higher-order components as previously suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on where those values are coming from. If they're typically hardcoded values (like `something={true}` in the question) then you can use default values that cover your most common cases.

If the values are coming from the parent that they're on (e.g. `myVar` and `something` in the question) then it depends on what those variables are and how they're set.

One potential solution would be to use the Context API (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Something above the `PageTemplate` could provide `myVar` and `something` via the Context through a ContextProvider.

PageTemplate could be modified to take the `somethingElse` prop, but if it's not provided to get the default value from the context itself.

Then your Products Page might look like this:

```
<PageTemplate>
   <Products />
</PageTemplate>
```

Where the `something` prop is set with a default value, and the `somethingElse` and `anotherThing` prop are retrieved from the Context. It's hard to provide a more specific answer without knowing a little about how the `myVar` and `something` values are typically being assigned.